# A questions about using basic rules to simplify complicated boolean algebra:

Tags: boolean-algebra, theorem-provers, boolean

When I was in the digital logic class at school, the teacher taught me basic Boolean algebra rules and some common simplification methods and then assigned some homework, but when I went to prove it myself, I found that I couldn't solve it.

When I read the proofs of these questions：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfoKS.png)

I'm getting more confused. I think I know the basic rules of Boolean algebra, but I can't figure out why it works here. In addition to the basic rules of Boolean algebra, are there any other ways to solve this problem using Boolean algebra? I tried to search for methods on the Internet but they were all simple proofs. I could understand them but they did not help me understand the above two proof questions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.